# improper behavior with infinite scroll plugin. Items dont line up right

Tags: plugins, wordpress

Edit: ~New Problem after initial problem was solved~

here's an example of whats going on:

http://soballer.com/product/ballin-on-a-budget/

the infinite scroll is working, but sometimes the products get mashed together and some spots on the grid dont get filled, it just skips down to the next row. I could use some help as I am very new to coding and such.

I took the advice of Chris A. below and changed my posts per page to 12. This solution works for a bit, but as you get to the 7th row, the order gets thrown off and the images get out of wack. I've tried changing the posts per page from 9 to 18 and still, ever setting produces this out of order effect.

Comment: Add more tags, as well as the name of the plugin to get better responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the number of items loaded to be a multiple of the width of the page. That is, your page loads the items 3 wide, so set your items loaded to be 9 or 12.

Comment: thank you sir. so easy that it tripped me up for a bit. :) but i got it